# Is there another way to add elements in js apart from using the ${} sign. Is not working for me on Visual studio code editor?

Tags: javascript, function

I want to add the apples and orange.

```
function fruitProcessor(apples, oranges) 
{console.log(apples, oranges);
 const juice = 'juice with ${apples} apples and ${oranges} oranges.';
 return juice;}
fruitProcessor(5, 0);
```

Comment: You need to use backticks for the string. Like this: `juice with ${apples} apples and ${oranges} oranges.` Instead of ' use ` -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score 1):

In order to interpolate variables in template literals, you should use a backtick instead of a quotation mark.

```
const juice = `juice with ${apples} apples and ${oranges} oranges.`;
```